# jQuery Full calndar - set fixed hight to date in month view

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm want to set that each day in month view will have a fixed height.

By default if there is events more then height of cell, its expands the date. (like example http://fullcalendar.io/views/month/).

Simple css do not work on td because the events are in fixed html.

How could i set each day in month to be "height:120px; overflow-y:scroll"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to a class the height you want with !imporant, that will override the inline style...

```
.fc-basic-view .fc-body .fc-row{ 
   height: 120px!important;
   overflow-y:scroll!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It adds scroll, but cell still is high as long the events.

Comment: which cell is higher in your example?

Comment: I have a month view with events. When there is more then 8 events, the cell of date gets longer. If you drag in the link in the question more then 4, it well happen.

Comment: Ok, I tried that too and I can still see the code I gave you is working fine for it, it remains 120px height.